# Short vs UShort: Hex to Decimal

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone pls send me a link where the method of converting from Hexadecimal to Decimal is explained? I am not understanding why the "Short" type variable is showing a negative sign in the below example...the literal seems to be the same in both cases. I understand UShort will not take signed values but then where is the negative sign even coming from ...the literals are exactly same in both cases. Is it because I am not understanding the rules of conversion from Hexadecimal to Decimal or is it something else?

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()

        Dim counter As Short = &H8000S 'Output: -32768
        Dim flags As UShort = &H8000US 'Output: 32768
        Console.WriteLine("O/P: {0}   {1}", counter, flags)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Have a look at [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: Print `short.MaxValue.ToString("X")`, then `Console.WriteLine(&HFFFFS) Console.WriteLine(&H8000S) Console.WriteLine(&H7FFFS)`